Nodejs Monorepo with Azure Functions fails at runtime for func start
I have a nodejs typescript monorepo set up in the below structure
libraries/
  lib1/
  lib2/
  package.json
  tsconfig.json
web-api/
  function1/
    function.json
    index.ts
  function2/
    function.json
    index.ts
  host.json
  package.json
  tsconfig.json
package.json
tsconfig.json

it is currently configured with workspaces in the root's package.json, and it builds fine if I run npm run build --workspace=web-api, however when I cd into web-api and try to run func start it throws a runtime error Worker was unable to load function function1: 'Cannot find module 'libraries/lib1/constants'
my nested tsconfig is set up to reference the libraries folder, and when web-api workspace is built, I see a dist folder with both libraries and web-api subfolders, so it pulls in all of the relevant js and mapping files that tsc builds, but for some reason func start is looking somewhere else. Is that additional plumbing that I need? Or am I executing it wrong?
UPDATE: link to a github repo that can reproduce the issue: https://github.com/jobeland/functionrepro
Steps:

navigate to root
npm install
npm run build --workspace=functionapp1
cd functionapp1
func start

expectation: function app runs successfully and http trigger is accessible
actual: function app fails to run because it can't find libraries folder.

Can you share your code repo if possible?

@PravallikaKV it's a private repo unfortunately. I can try and spin up a test repo to reproduce it though.

Please share your test repo.

@PravallikaKV I've updated the description with the link to a reduced repro repository and steps to follow.

please check if the solution below helps you. Let me know if there's anything else I can assist with.

I got the same error when I ran the code you have shared.
Resolution:
Modify the import statement in functionapp1/index.js:
Use
const  constants  =  require('../../libraries/common/constants');

instead of
import  *  as  constants  from  "libraries/common/constants";

I'm able to import the libraries and run the function successfully:

npm run build:

C:\Users\uname\customlib\functionrepro>npm run build

> functionrepro@1.0.0 build
> tsc


cd functionapp1
npm start

C:\Users\uname\functionrepro\functionapp1>npm start

> functionapp1@1.0.0 prestart
> npm run build

> functionapp1@1.0.0 build
> tsc

> functionapp1@1.0.0 start
> func start

Azure Functions Core Tools
Core Tools Version:       4.0.5700 Commit hash: N/A +71cc84964a60bfb07d95839b7c666bd239507bdd (64-bit)
Function Runtime Version: 4.33.2.22572

[2024-06-17T13:15:31.642Z] Worker process started and initialized.

Functions:

        HttpTriggerGreeting: [GET] http://localhost:7071/api/greeting

For detailed output, run func with --verbose flag.
[2024-06-17T13:15:36.401Z] Host lock lease acquired by instance ID '000000000000000000000000F72731CC'.
[2024-06-17T13:15:36.806Z] Executing 'Functions.HttpTriggerGreeting' (Reason='This function was programmatically called via the host APIs.', Id=11f7b13f-a6d9-4aee-91ce-c55a53c3c965)
[2024-06-17T13:15:37.068Z] Executed 'Functions.HttpTriggerGreeting' (Succeeded, Id=11f7b13f-a6d9-4aee-91ce-c55a53c3c965, Duration=296ms)

Output:

